# SharePoint 2013 Header/Detail Expense Form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

We are stuck with what we know seems to be an easy solution, however, just can't seem to get it done.

We are trying to implement a Expense Management form that allows a user claim back expenses. The form is actually quite simple and can be done easily using a form library, however, what is holding us down is the reporting.

**How it works:**

- Expense Header: Supplier, Transaction Date, Comments
- Expense Detail: Expense Type, Amount

Problem:

1. We tried using a repeating table, which works, however management needs to see reporting per expense type, and info
2. Im sure there are other solutions involving having 2 forms, the problem is that the user might open the detail form and choose the wrong lookup to invoice header and all the expenses might go under the wrong expense.

Any ideas that might assist? We are trying for a code-less solution, however we are open to CAML/Jquery etc.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with the repeating table, but how it has been done in the past that I've seen, is using REST/CSOM and the PreSaveAction to commit those repeating table rows to another list called "Expenses" and the actual form commits to the list "Expense Reports". The Expenses are linked through the ID of the Expense Report.

Comment: Hi Mike
Thanks for your reply. Any idea on where I can find some resources to assist me with REST/CSOM using infopath?